# Date problem with asymmetric waiting time

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Two people are going on a blind coffee date, one of them will show up randomly at a time between 12:00 and 12:45, and stay for 30 minutes before leaving. The other will show up randomly at a time between 12:30 and 13:00 , and stay for 15 minutes before leaving. What is the probability that the two actually meet?

Numerically I got an answer of about $67$%. I am aware of the solution for the case of symmetrical waiting time and arrival times, but I am unsure how to generalize it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the solution cleaner, I will scale the time such that "$0 \cong 12:00$" and "$1\cong 13:00$". I will also assume that the arrival times are independent:

Let $X$ be the arrival time of the first person and $Y$ be the arrival time of the second person. Since we're dealing with uniform distributions, $X \sim U\left([0,\frac{3}{4}]\right)$ and $Y \sim U\left([\frac{1}{2},1]\right)$. Geometrically, graphing the density function of $(X,Y)$, we therefore get a ["rectangle"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeF9u.png) of constant height.

Now to the interesting bit: The first person is in the coffee shop during the time interval $[X, X + \frac{1}{2}]$ and the second person during the time interval $[Y, Y + \frac{1}{4}]$. Asking for them to meet, is equivalent to $[X, X + \frac{1}{2}] \cap [Y, Y + \frac{1}{4}] \neq \emptyset$ (i.e. the time intervals of the two intersecting), so

1. $X + \frac{1}{2} \geq Y$ and
2. $Y + \frac{1}{4} \geq X \iff Y \geq X - \frac{1}{4}$.

Again, as we're dealing with uniform distributions, the probability that they'll meet is given by the ["portion of the rectangle"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJzLi.png) for which 1. (in red) and 2. (in purple) holds.

That the portion is exactly $\frac{2}{3}$, should be clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that the two can miss each other is if the 1st person leaves before the 2nd person gets there.

If the 2nd person arrives at 12:30 + $t$ (minutes) then the chances of a miss are $\frac{t}{45}$.

Therefore, the chance of a miss are

$$\frac{\int_0^{30} \frac{t}{45} dt}{\int_0^{30} (1)dt}
= \frac{\frac{30^2}{2 \times 45}}{30} = \frac{1}{3}
.\tag1$$

In (1) above, the denominator is used to normalize the probability represented by the numerator.

**Addendum**
As suggested by the answer of MXXZ, an alternative approach would be to reason that with respect to the probability function referred to in (1) above, the function is **linear**.

Therefore, you can reason that the overall probability of a miss will equal the average probability of $\displaystyle \left(\frac{t}{45}\right)$, as $t$ ranges from $(0)$ through $(30)$.

Since the probability function is linear, the average value will occur when $t$ is at the midpoint of the interval $[0,30].$  Therefore, the overall chance of a miss must be $\displaystyle \left(\frac{15}{45}\right)$.

Comment: How did you determine the normalizing term?

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni Suppose that the chance of a miss was 100% (i.e. absolute certainty), regardless of the value of $t$.  Then, the numerator would change to $\int_0^{30} (1) dt$.  Absolute certainty equates to a probability of $(1)$.  Given what the numerator would have to look like, the denominator must be adjusted so that if the chance of a miss is $(1)$, the corresponding ratio between numerator and denominator is also $(1)$.

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni See also the just added Addendum to my answer.